# How do you define view model in Go

Tags: templates, go, view, model

I would like to define a structure for View model, something looks like:

```
type AdminView struct {
    PageTitle string
    UserName string
    UserType string
    Templates []Template
    ...
    OtherAttr Other
}
```

to help me organize templates and DTO better, but haven't worked very well so far. What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
func adminViewHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := processRequestData (r)  // process request form data
    view := AdminView {}
    // then assign values to view
    view.render(w) // similar to tmpl.Exec(w, data)
}
```

I'd like to know if I am on the right track to introduce more abstraction in rendering the View using the approach above. I would like to know how people render complex view with complex data in real world, too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask only *one* question at a time. The first question was too broad and primarily opinion based anyway, so I've removed that part. Also see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost on track. Remember that Go is not an object-oriented language, so inheritance (what you're trying to do) is not a very common pattern.

Instead what you would do is use a template, and pass the view model into the template:

```
view := AdminView{}
...
tmpl.Exec(w, view)
```